# Dynamic memory allocation in c++ without a variable

Tags: c++

I am learning the dynamic memory allocation process in c++.

1.How to declare dynamic memory allocation of an array without prior knowledge of the size?

2.Suppose I use a variable to dynamically allocate memory to the array but later on in the program the size of array is reduced.Will there be automatic de-allocation of memory?

If not then how to update it?

Please spare me if these are silly questions.If you answer please include an example program.

Comment: Just use `std::vector`. It takes care of the memory management.

Comment: As the programmer, when you use dynamically allocated memory, you have to do all of the memory management. I.e. allocation, keeping track of it, and deallocation. This includes resizing (creating a new different sized array and copying the elements over to the new one) it when you think is necessary. This is a lot of work, so I'd suggest using the c++ standard containers (`std::vector`).

Comment: You might want to read about the rule of zero. https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1896 It touches on the complexity of resource management.

Comment: This is too broad, what research have you done?

Comment: Just a note: remember `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` (and `std::make_unique`/`std::make_shared`) exist. Don't use manual memory management with raw pointers in modern C++ (except *very* rarely and for *extremely* good reasons (which you won't know as a new learner)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ***Cheers and hth*** said in the comments, the best way is to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), it takes care of the memory management itself.

---

> 1. How to declare dynamic memory allocation of an array without prior knowledge of the size?

The idea is, you do not allocate any memory if you do not know the size, and when adding elements to it, you can increase the memory, see example below.

**Implementing a class that works like `std::vector`**:

`vector` uses two sizes, one is the `size` which is the number of elements your `vector` is currently holding, `capacity` is the number of elements which your `vector` can hold (memory is allocated for `capacity`)

**Pre-requisites**: I'm assuming that you know the basic memory allocation and de-allocation, that you can allocate memory using `new` operator, and de-allocate using `delete` operator.

**Note**: I'm implementing some methods for `MyIntVector` that uses only `int` array for simplicity, but you can always implement a templated class.

**Implementation**:

You can provide a default constructor for your class, which doesn't allocate any memory, sets the `size` and `capacity` to `0` (client programs can use this constructor, if the size is not known).

You can also provide a constructor which takes a `size` that will be used as the starting `size`, when creating the `MyIntVector`

Also provide a destructor to completely de-allocate the allocated memory.

```
class MyIntVector{

    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity;
    int* _data;

public:
    MyIntVector(){
        _size = 0;
        _capacity = 0;
        _data = nullptr;
    }
    MyIntVector(size_t size){
        _size = size;
        _capacity = size;
        _data = new int[_capacity];
    }
    ~MyIntVector(){
        if (_data){
            delete[] _data;
        }
        _data = nullptr;
        _size = _capacity = 0;
    }
};
```

Now, if you want to add some element to your `MyIntVector`, you can implement a `push_back` function, like `std::vector` does.

```
class MyIntVector{
    //...
    void push_back(int elem){

        if (_size >= _capacity){
            // Oops, we're out of memory, let's make room for this elem first
            resize(_capacity > 0? _capcity * 2 : 10);
        }
        // Now, there's enough memory to hold this elem
        _size++;
        _data[_size - 1] = elem;
    }

    void resize(size_t newCapacity){
        if (newCapacity != _capacity){
            if (_size == 0){
                _capacity = newCapacity;
                _data = new int[_capacity];
            }
            else {
                // create a temporary array to hold the elements of _data
                int* temp = new int[_size];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < _size; i++)
                    temp[i] = _data[i];

                // de-allocate the memory of _data
                delete[] _data;

                // allocate memory in _data with newCapacity
                _capacity = newCapacity;
                _data = new int[_capacity];

                // copy the elements of temporary array back in _data
                for (size_t i = 0; i < _size; i++){
                    _data[i] = temp[i];
                }

                // done with the temporary array, de-allocate it.
                delete[] temp;
                temp = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }

    //...
};
```

**`push_back` function**:

The `push_back` function, that I've implemented in above example, it sees whether the new element can be added to the `MyIntVector` without any need to allocate any new memory or not, if not, it just increases the `_size` by `1` and copies the element. If there's a need for new memory, it calls the `resize` method with doubled capacity (in case, there's already some allocated memory there.) or some hard-coded value, say `10` (in case, where there's not any previously allocated memory)

**`resize` function**:

The `resize` function takes a `newCapacity` as argument, and allocates the required memory in `_data`, mainly it creates a temporary array to hold the elements of `_data` and then de-allocates the memory in `_data`, allocates a larger memory in `_data`, copies back the from `temp` to `_data` and de-allocates the `temp` array.

***Note***: This implementation of `resize` should only be used when *increasing* the `_capacity`, it should **not** be called for *decreasing* the `_capacity`

---

So, the idea is, that you can increase the size of the array, by using a temporary array for holding the elements, de-allocating the previous array, allocating a new array, and copying back the elements from temporary array. You can implement different methods that `std::vector` provides for your exercise.

If you don't want to de-allocate and re-allocate the memory every time you increase the capacity, you can always implement a Linked List, [here](http://pumpkinprogrammer.com/2014/06/13/c-tutorial-intro-to-linked-lists/)'s a tutorial for implementing a Linked List, but there's a drawback of Linked List, that you can't randomly access elements from the Linked List like you can from an array.

---

> 2. Suppose I use a variable to dynamically allocate memory to the array but later on in the program the size of array is reduced.Will there be automatic de-allocation of memory?

There's no automatic de-allocation of memory, you'll have to manually decrease the `_capacity` if you want.

You can add a `pop_back` method in your `MyIntVector` class to remove an element.

```
class MyIntVector{
    // ...
    int pop_back(){
        if (_size == 0){
            // You can throw some exception here if you want.
            throw exception("No elements found");
        }
        _size--;
        return _data[_size];
    }
    // ...
};
```

You can manually decrease the `_capacity` before returning the element.

You can also provide an implementation of subscript operator `[]` for your `MyIntVector` class to provide random access in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you do choose to dynamically allocate memory, you will need to use the operator new[] for an array, which is considered a different operator in c++ than new for non-array types.

1) Here is an example of how to dynamically allocate an array:

```
int length = 10;
int *myArray = new int[length];

// do something
myArray[0] = 42;
```

When you are done, you will need to release the memory with delete[]:

```
delete[] myArray;
```

2) No, there is no automatic de-allocation of dynamically allocated memory in C++ unless you are using smart pointers ([What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)).

If you want to resize your array, you will have to do it manually:

```
delete[] myArray;

int newLength = 5;
myArray = new int[newLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

As @frameworks pointed out, you will need the operator `new[]` to allocate memory for an array and you need to call `delete[]` to free that memory. If there is no `delete[]` for a `new[]`, your program will leak memory. (If there is more than one `delete[]` called for a single `new[]`, your program will segfault / crash.)

However, it is not always trivial to ensure that memory allocated with `new[]` (or `new`) gets always cleaned up by a corresponding `delete[]` (or `delete`), and only gets cleaned up once. That is especially true for code with complex control flow, code where pointers get passed around or situations where exceptions can be thrown between `new[]` and `delete[]`.

In other words: Wherever there is a `new`, there probably is a leak.

**So to save you all that trouble of manual memory management, use `std::vector` instead.** This container takes care of the memory management for you.

Whenever you are tempted to write something like

```
int *myArray = new int[3];
//do something with myArray
delete[] myArray;
```

you should write

```
std::vector<int> myArray;
//do something with myArray
```

instead. You do not need a delete here and methods like [std::vector::push_back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) take care of the required size adjustments for the underlying structure, should it not provide enough space to accomodate all pushed values. You can also use [std::vector::shrink_to_fit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) to remove unused elements. (However, shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request to reduce the internal size. That is, results may vary between compilers.)